# tensor product of finite-dimensional irreducible modules for a semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

How to prove the following statement:

> If $g$ is a semisimple Lie algebra, then the tensor product of finite-dimensional irreducible modules possesses the crucial property of being fully reducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple then *all* of its finite-dimensional modules are completely reducible (in characteristic zero) --- that's [Weyl's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_theorem_on_complete_reducibility)